# I cannot center cell.imageview inside of the UItableview as a programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I designed a drop down menu for Swift 4. In order to do this I used a button and tableview. I am trying to center the imageview() by using `cell.imageview` but I get an error.

Here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    customImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.imageView?.image = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row].bankImage

    //  Constraints that i used.
    cell.imageView?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: customImageView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    cell.imageView?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: customImageView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    return cell
}
```

Here is error when I try to give constraints.

[Full Project](https://github.com/bkkelleroglu/DropDownExample)

> DropDownExample[4701:223823] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000285190 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9386d09ad0.centerX == UIImageView:0x7f9386d04cf0.centerX   (inactive)>
>   When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>   2018-10-11 17:13:24.499450+0300 DropDownExample[4701:223823] [LayoutConstraints] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.

Comment: `let cell = UITableViewCell()` Don't do that, cells are reused. Also, check that cell.imageView.superview == cell.contentView

Comment: You need to subclass the ```UITableViewCell`` to achieve anything you want, for full customization. And Larme is correct. I guess you need to study the fundamentals of using the ```UITableView``` first.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions to my problem.I created whole things as a programmatically.I just shared the link of my project.Can u just check out fully and give me a feedback pls cuz i don't understand solution which you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

First better don't create a new UITableViewCell() better use:

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

This will create new cells only if needed. But be aware of the reuse case.

In your case you always get a UITableViewCell with default style. This results in an image and a textlabel. You can't customize this kind of cell well.
Better create a prototype cell inside your storyboard and dequeue it. A custom cell can get customized completely.

If you don't wont to use storyboards - add a Custom TableViewCell class with a xib file and register it for reuse within the tableview.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "myCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Comment: Can you fully review my project pls :) ? i actually shared.

Comment: Are you sure the project works fine? I'll get a crash when tapping the button on top of the screen. (Xcode 10)

Comment: Could you assign rights to me I can push an update? Look for Kai Teuber
AppDevelopersDE on GitHub

Comment: I assigned on the project.Thank you.

Comment: Created a pull request - have a look on the new file I created (by help if Xcode) with the xib file. i register this nib on the table view and load it via dequeue. After successfully loading (I used a guard) I can assign values to it.
All the layout work can be done in Interface builder or on awakeFromNib / cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping.That's what i wanted.